# How find all usage (using emacs) some elisp function in all *.el files in Emacs?

Tags: elisp

Emacs ver. 25.1.1

All emacs source files are in folder: ...\emacs\share\emacs\25.1\lisp\

Suppose I open in emacs file **url.el**. In this file has function **url-retrieve**.
How I can found (using emacs) what another ***.el** files use this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use `xref-find-references` (new in Emacs-25), which by default is bound to <kbd>M-?</kbd>.

It is meant to be generic, so it should work not only in Elisp, but in any major mode which provides support for xref.